# Mobi as a name prefix

Tags: pronunciation, names

I'm about to create a new business name, using Mobi as a first part of the name.

Someting like: MobiChat, MobiWork, MobiScan, MobiLease, you get the idea.

Does that sound unusual to a native English speaker's ear? How is it pronounced? I assume it rhymes with "lobby".

Thanks!

Comment: I recognize it as short for "mobile" but it does sound unusual to my ear. It has far greater currency among programmers than among the population taken as a whole. It is still a very new prefix. I have never literally heard it--have only seen it in writing.

Comment: Here in Belgium, the company _Mobistar_ is pronounced as one would pronounce _mobystar_. So even if the _i_ comes from _mobile_, it is not pronounced as it is in the original word.

Comment: Here in the US, people pronounce the -ile of mobile phone in a couple of ways, something close to but a little lower than schwa (mobul) or rhyming with 'aisle' [aI]. There is also a kind of art that hangs suspended (a mobile) and then the suffix rhymes with "wheel".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It scans perfectly fine, and when I see MobiChat I assume it's short for Mobile Chat.

In British English at least, Mobi doesn't rhyme with lobby. It actually rhymes with pony (okay not quite, it rhymes perfectly with Adobe if you've heard how that word is pronounced).

Comment: Thanks Mark. And how about Moby vs Mobi?

Comment: Both of those words would be pronounced exactly the same. The only difference is if a company is called MobyChat, I no longer think it's short for Mobile Chat.

Comment: @Ra. _Mobychat_ sounds like a communication protocol for whales, because of _Moby Dick_.

Comment: @oerkelens: or a special fan-forum for the artist who goes by the name "Moby" (Richard Melville Hall, distantly related to the novelist).

Comment: Mobi and Moby sound the same in American English, too. (If you want Mobby, to rhyme with lobby, you need double-B.)